# how to output database data in a php select menu tag

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-select

I can't seem to figure out how to correctly display a select menu outputting mysql data from a database. I want to output blog titles so the user can upload pictures to that selected blog according to the category they selected in the select menu. Here are the files:

form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Choose a file:<br /><input type="file" name="image" /></p>
<p>
Choose an album:<br />
<select name="album_id">
    <?php 
    foreach ($albums as $album){
        echo '<option value="', $album['id'], '">', $album['name'], '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select><br /><br />
Choose an blog:<br />
<select name="post_id">
    <?php

    foreach ($posts as $post){
        echo '<option value="', $post['id'], '">', $post['title'], '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

and here is the posts.php file:

```
<?php

//checks if the given post id is in the table
function valid_pid($pid) {
$pid = (int)$pid;

$total = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`post_id`) FROM `posts` WHERE `post_id` = {$pid}");
$total = mysql_result($total, 0);

if ($total != 1) {
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
}

//gets a summary of all blog posts
function get_posts() {
$sql = "SELECT
            `posts`.`post_id` AS `id`,
            `posts`.`post_title` AS `title`,
            LEFT(`posts`.`post_body`, 512) AS `preview`,
            `posts`.`post_user` AS `user`,
            DATE_FORMAT(`posts`.`post_date`, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS `date`,
            `comments`.`total_comments`,
            DATE_FORMAT(`comments`.`last_comment`, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS `last_comment`
        FROM `posts`
        LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT
                `post_id`,
                COUNT(`comment_id`) AS `total_comments`,
                MAX(`comment_date`) AS `last_comment`
            FROM `comments`
            GROUP BY `post_id`
        ) AS `comments`
        ON `posts`.`post_id` = `comments`.`post_id`
        ORDER BY `posts`.`post_date` DESC";

$posts = mysql_query($sql);

 $rows = array();
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts)) !== false) {
            $rows[] = array(
                    'id'                       => $row['id'],
                    'title'                   => $row['title'],
                    'preview'             => $row['preview'],
                    'user'                   => $row['user'],
                    'date'                   => $row['date'],
                    'total_comments' => ($row['total_comments'] === null) ? 0 : $row['total_comments'],
                    'last_comment'     => ($row['last_comment'] === null) ? 'none' : $row['last_comment']
            );
}

return $rows;
}

//gets a single post from the table
function get_post($pid) {
$pid = (int)$pid;

$sql = "SELECT
            `post_title` AS `title`,
            `post_body` AS `body`,
            `post_user` AS `user`,
            `post_date` AS `date`
        FROM `posts`
        WHERE `post_id` = {$pid}";

$post = mysql_query($sql);
$post = mysql_fetch_assoc($post);

$post['comments'] = get_comments($pid);

return $post;
}

//adds a new blog entry
function add_post($name, $title, $body) {
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($name));
$title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($title));
$body = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($body)));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_user`, `post_title`, `post_body`, `post_date`) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$title}', '{$body}', NOW())");
}

?>
```

Thanks for any help!

-TechGuy24

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `<select>` block to the following

```
<select name="album_id">
    <?php 
    foreach ($albums as $album){
        echo '<option value="'. $album['id'].'">'. $album['name'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select><br /><br />
Choose an blog:<br />
<select name="post_id">
    <?php

    foreach ($posts as $post){
        echo '<option value="'. $post['id']. '">'. $post['title'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

In your `post.php` change the `while()` block of `get_posts()` to the following

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts)) {
            $rows[] = array(
                    'id'                       => $row['id'],
                    'title'                   => $row['title'],
                    'preview'             => $row['preview'],
                    'user'                   => $row['user'],
                    'date'                   => $row['date'],
                    'total_comments' => ($row['total_comments'] === null) ? 0 : $row['total_comments'],
                    'last_comment'     => ($row['last_comment'] === null) ? 'none' : $row['last_comment']
            );
}
```

Comment: give me the output of `print_r($albums)`

Comment: @TechGuy24, He just replaced the commas into points. And it's correctly.

Comment: Array([0]=>Array ( [id] => 8 [timestamp] => 1346477013 [name] => Florida [description] => My Florida phot [count] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 9 [timestamp] => 1346477313 [name] => Georgia [description] => My Photos of Ge [count] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 10 [timestamp] => 1346533161 [name] => Indiana [description] => Some stuff abou [count] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 11 [timestamp] => 1346533190 [name] => Tennessee [description] => Some stuff abou [count] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 12 [timestamp] => 1346533217 [name] => Washington [description] => Some stuff abou [count] => 0 ) ) 1

Comment: the first select tag works fine, It's the second one that won't output the data from the database

Comment: @TechGuy24 In that case what is the output of `print_r($posts)` if it is null post the block where you construct the array `$posts`

Comment: it comes up with this error: "Notice: Undefined variable: posts in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\Image Upload\upload_image.php on line 59"

Comment: where are u initializing `$posts` ??

Comment: right above the form. I didn't post the whole code because there are other php code that doesn't pertain to this but I can post it if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Choose a file:<br /><input type="file" name="image" /></p>
<p>
Choose an album:<br />
<select name="album_id">
<?php 
foreach ($albums as $album){
    echo '<option value="', $album['id'], '">', $album['name'], '</option>';
}
?>
</select><br /><br />
Choose an blog:<br />
<select name="post_id">
<?php 
$rsPost = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY");
$post=mysql_fetch_assoc("$rsPost");
do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $post['id'];?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></option>
<?php } while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPost)); ?>
```

Maybe this helps!

Comment: Where is your call to the get_post() function?

Comment: It was above the form but i had to take it out because it kept making page show nothing but a blank screen. I know it should be there but I'm not sure where I can put it where it won't give me a blank screen..

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind everyone! Sorry for the confusion..I placed my get_posts(); = posts in a wrong part of the script. I had to put it above an if statement that was checking something else. Works perfectly now! Thanks!!